# Paramiko SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have four raspberry pis with raspbian running on them. Now I need to execute the same shell commands on each of the hosts. I can't automate the jobs using cron because they are diffrent everytime I need to do it.
So I figured I could write a python script doing it for me:

```
hosts = ["host1", "host2", "host3", "host4"]
usrs = ["usr1", "usr2", "usr3", "usr4"]
passwords = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4"]

def do_ssh_stuff(host, usr, pwd):
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  try:
    ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=usr, password=pwd)
    # Do the stuff on the remote machine

  except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    print("Failed on machine: " + host)

i = 0

for host in hosts:
   do_ssh_stuff(host, usr[i], passwords[i])
   i += 1
i = 0
```

The thing is sometimes it seems to work and other times it I get this error message:

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1893, in _check_banner
buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 331, in readline
buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 488, in _read_timeout
raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1749, in run
self._check_banner()
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1897, in _check_banner
raise SSHException('Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1893, in _check_banner
buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 331, in readline
buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 488, in _read_timeout
raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/usr/ownCloud/Server/Hacking in Python/Ssh-Cracker.py", line 45, in <module>
do_ssh_stuff("192.168.178.49", "usr", "passwd")
File "C:/Users/usr/ownCloud/Server/Hacking in Python/Ssh-Cracker.py", line 26, in do_ssh_stuff
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=usr, password=pwd)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\client.py", line 338, in connect
t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 500, in start_client
raise e
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1749, in run
self._check_banner()
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1897, in _check_banner
raise SSHException('Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

I tried setting the banner timeout in transport.py from 15 to 30 sec without any success.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does your Ssh-Cracker.py involve failed login attempts, i.e. attempt different passwords or users against the same host with some of the attempts failing to login because of a wrong user/password combination?

Comment: No I can log in with the credentials just fine. I checked the /var/log/auth.log and it give me the following output:
   
Mar  4 18:58:57 PI-NAS sshd[31762]: Accepted password for usr from 192.168.178.43 port 55042 ssh2
Mar  4 18:58:57 PI-NAS sshd[31762]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user usr by (uid=0)

But something like:

Mar  3 20:08:34 PI-NAS sshd[31046]: Connection closed by 192.168.178.43 [preauth]
Mar  3 20:08:34 PI-NAS sshd[31074]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]

for the failed connections.